# Why doesn't `tar --exclude` take multiple options?

Tags: tar, wildcards

Looking at the man-page for tar it's stated that `--exclude=PATTERN` will " *exclude files, given as a PATTERN* ".  I'm not sure if PATTERN is explained in more detail somewhere else, but why does the user have to supply a separate `--exclude` option for every directory or file? For example,

```
tar cvzf backup.tar.gz / --exclude=/home,/sys,/proc
```

as opposed to

```
tar cvzf backup.tar.gz / --exclude=/home --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to *[6.4 Excluding Some Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC109)*  in the manual. In addition to accepting multiple `--exclude` options, GNU tar has this option, for multiple patterns:

> **`-X`**, **`--exclude-from`** *FILE*
>   exclude patterns listed in *FILE*

In the manual, it explains that *patterns* are shell wildcards.

As for *why* it does it this way: longstanding convention uses a single value from a command-line option which takes a value.  If each program invented different ways of parsing command-lines, it would be more work to maintain.